# Trouble deploying reaction commerce project on AWS

Tags: node.js, reaction-commerce

I installed reaction commerce on my local machine - everything is working fine but when I deploy it on AWS it's not working.

It's showing:

> Setting up plugin imports
>   Setting up style imports
>   Provisioning assets

Comment: Are you deploying the production version? Looks like you're trying to use a developer image on a server, which I believe isn't what you want to do.

Comment: yes deploying the production mode

Comment: Can you please update your post to include the steps you went through to build the image and deploy it?